# Format int to hex string

Tags: c#, hex, tostring

I have some int values that I want to convert to a string but in hex.
This hex value should be formatted always by 2 digits.

Example below:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

//returns the value in hex
string c = a.toString("x"); // a
string d = b.toString("x"); // 14
```

What I want is that always that the hex value results in two digits. Shows like "0a", not only "a".

I'm using convert a int to a formatted string,

```
int e = 1;
string f = e.toString("D2"); // 01
```

Have a way to the two things together? To convert the int to a hex formatted string?

Comment: There is a buil-in function to do this.  Why are you building a new function to do something that already exists?  If you are wondering all you do is get the bits of the integer then display the string and add the `0x` to the string.

Comment: @Ramhound: It's not at all clear what you mean. The OP is reusing the existing `ToString` method, not building his own... and there's no indication that he wants "0x" in the string at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use this

```
int e = 1;
string f = e.toString("x2");
```

Answer (score 5):

> Have a way to the two things togheter?

Yes - you just use `x2`. You already have the hex bit with `x` and the "2 characters" part with `D2` - you just need to combine them.

See the documentation for [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for more information.